# How to set the opacity of sprite in p5.play?

Tags: p5.play

In p5.play I want to set a sprite's opacity(like Fade). How can I do that?

```
sprite.opacity = 0.5 //something like that
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this, depending on what you're trying to make transparent.

1. Changing the color

This method can only be used if you don't plan on adding images to your sprites. We can use this basic function:

```
sprite.shapeColor.setAlpha(50)
```

As I said, this method can only be used with colors.

2. Changing the images

It is by no means efficient, but it technically works

```
tint(255, 0-255);
drawSprites(sprite);
tint(255)
```